# Loop through the ResultSet in an efficient way and add column values to List<String>

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, resultset

I am working on a multithreaded project in which each thread will `randomly find columns for that table` and I will be using those columns in my `SELECT sql query` and then I will be executing that SELECT sql query. AFter exectuing that query, I will be looping through the result set and will add the data for each columns into `List<String>`.

Here `columnsList` will contains `columns` delimited by `comma`. For example-

`col1, col2, col3`

Below is my code.

```
class ReadTask implements Runnable {

public ReadTask() {

}


@Override
public run() {
  ...

  while ( < 60 minutes) {

    .....

    final int id = generateRandomId(random);
    final String columnsList = getColumns(table.getColumns());
    final String selectSql = "SELECT " + columnsList + "  from " + table.getTableName() + " where id = ?";
    resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    List<String> colData = new ArrayList<String>(columnsList.split(",").length);
    boolean foundData = false;

    if (id >= startValidRange && id <= endValidRange) {

        if (resultSet.next()) {
            foundData = true;
            for (String column : columnsList.split(",")) {
                colData.add(resultSet.getString(column.trim()));
            }
            resultSet.next();//do I need this here?
        }
    } else if (resultSet.next()) {
        addException("Data Present for Non Valid ID's", Read.flagTerminate);
    }

    ....
      }
   }


    private static void addException(String cause, boolean flagTerminate) {
        AtomicInteger count = exceptionMap.get(cause);
        if (count == null) {
            count = new AtomicInteger();
            AtomicInteger curCount = exceptionMap.putIfAbsent(cause, count);
            if (curCount != null) {
                count = curCount;
            }
        }
        count.incrementAndGet();

        if(flagTerminate) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

After executing the `SELECT` sql query. Below are my two scenarios-

1. I need to see whether the id is between the valid range. If it is between the Valid Range then check whether `resultSet` has any data or not. If it has data then loop around the `resultSet` using the `columns` from the `columnsList` and start adding it in `coldData` list of String.
2. else if id is not in the valid range then I need to check I am not getting any data back from the `resultSet`. But somehow if I am getting the data back and flag is true to stop the program, then exit the program. Else if I am getting the data back but flag is false to stop the program, then count how many of those happening. So for this, I have created `addException` method.

Can anyone help me out whether the way I am doing here for my above two `scenarios` is right or not? It looks like, I can improve the `if/else loop` code more I guess for my above two scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a few things you could do to make the code a bit faster:

Regarding the query part, if the table never changes, you could move the `columnsList` initialization outside the while loop, and perhaps even make it static if all the threads use the same query. Likewise, you are recomputing the split and trimmed columns list out of this variable for each query result. This could be done once for all outside the loop.

Regarding the test itself, indeed you could reverse the nesting. You're currently doing something like:

```
if (B) {
   if (A) ok;
}
else if (A) error;
```

when it could be more simply written:

```
if (A){
   if (B) ok;
   else error;
}
```

Your code could be better stated as follow:

```
if (resultSet.next()) {
    if (id >= startValidRange && id <= endValidRange) {
        foundData = true;
        for (String column : columnsList.split(",")) {
            colData.add(resultSet.getString(column.trim()));
        }
    }
    else
        addException("Data Present for Non Valid ID's", Read.flagTerminate);
}
```

Regarding the exceptions logging part, you should avoid the static method to handle the storage directly in the map, it's a failry strong source of contention and will prevent your threads to focus on doing their real work, which is launching and processing queries. Typically, accessing a map has a time complexity in `O(log n)`, and looking at your code, you are doing that access twice, and do all sort of checks to make sure that the accounting is correct. Comparatively, pushing a value in a queue is a constant time operation, and synchronisation is handled by the queue itself.

So, my advice here is to delegate the handling of the map to a dedicated thread, and add a synchronized queue for your query threads to give it their exceptions. That way you won't need to deal with concurrent accesses to your map (this can be messy).  Again, from the query threads standpoint, the logging process will be a simple "fire and forget" action, and the logging thread will just have to pull new messages from the queue and add them to the map.

If you don't already know how to build such a setup, there's [the Oracle tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0160__Thread/SynchronizedQueuewithProducerandConsumer.htm). There are also several SO questions and answers on the topic (producer-consumer).

Update: if you want to even reduce contention, you can create one queue per query thread, and make the map thread check all the queue in turn. The risk of concurrent access is reduced to two threads at the same time: one query thread and the map thread. It will induce a bit more work in the map thread, but at the same time will avoid many threads rescheduling (which happens each time a thread is blocked by a lock). The less reschedule happens, the less time is spent on thread management, and the more time is available for real work.

Note that at any rate, you should be careful that not too many items pile up in the queue(s). If that scenario is likely to happen (which I doubt, but I don't know the details of your data to be certain), you might want to use BlockingQueues (look up the class description, and SO questions on the topic for further details).

Comment: Thanks didierc for the suggestion. In my case table will be changing everytime inside the while loop. And what about my two scenarios? Is there any way I can make that more efficient? It is looking ugly currently. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Aaah.. I added one extra check. Thanks for pointing that out. One more thing you mentioned in your answer was `Regarding the exceptions logging part, you should avoid the static method to handle the storage directly in the map, it's a failry strong source of contention` Can you explain me why it will be strong source of contention? I just wanted to understand from the knowledge point of view. Thanks fort he help. And how can I improve that method as I mentioned that I am using that method in my else loop. Thanks for the help.

Comment: And most important thing I forgot here. What about thread safety issues here with the `List<String> colData`? I need to make that synchronized right? As multiple thread will be writing into it. If yes how can I correct that in my code to avoid Thread Safety issues. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: From what I see, `colData` in your code is completely local to each thread, no need for synchronization.